# Multiple InfoWindows Android Maps V2

Tags: java, android, google-maps

So my application requires me to create a route for a certain bus. I have accomplished this and have created a custom info window for the marker. Now, I was asked to add a feature in which I need to show on the map POIs (points of interests) around the marker. I have successfully created this. However, I want a different Info window for these POI markers.

Here is my first info window:

```
    public class InfoAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {
    LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    private TextView textViewstopName;
    private TextView arrivalTime;
    public InfoAdapter(LayoutInflater inflater) {
        this.inflater = inflater;
    }
    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.businfo_layout, null);
        if (marker != null) {
            textViewstopName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.businfo);
            textViewstopName.setText(marker.getTitle());
            arrivalTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.arrivalinfo);
            arrivalTime.setText(marker.getSnippet());
        }
        return (v);
    }
    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        return (null);
    }
}
```

And here is my second one (I wanted to have to default one for the POIs for now):

```
    public class PlacesAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter{
    LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    public PlacesAdapter(LayoutInflater inflater) {
        this.inflater = inflater;
    }
    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is where I called the first one:

```
    private void SetupStopMarkers(){
    map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoAdapter(getLayoutInflater()));
    addMarkersToMap(markerPoints);
}
```

Here is where I called the second one:

```
else{
            map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new PlacesAdapter(getLayoutInflater()));
    ...
    }
```

My info_layout:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="1"
android:background="@drawable/businfo_dialog">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/busicon"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:src="@drawable/busstop_icon"/>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/clockicon"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/busicon"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/clock"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/businfo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/busicon"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/busicon"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/arrivalinfo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/businfo"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/clockicon"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/clockicon"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/placesinfo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/arrivalinfo"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="35dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:textColor="#0099cc"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/more_info"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/eta_i"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/arrivalinfo"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/arrivalinfo"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/arrivalinfo"
    android:text="ETA:"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

But after calling the second info window, every marker in the map changes to that second info window.  Is there a way to do this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you share exactly what you're trying to accomplish?  You can't have multiple InfoWindowAdapters set,  but you should be able to add functionality to your existing InfoWindowAdapter to achieve your desired result.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I have two different markers: A position marker and B POI markers. I have a custom infowindow for A but I'm trying to show a different infowindow B for the POI markers.

Comment: I think the best way to do it would be to inflate different layouts in the InfoWindowAdapter depending on the type of Marker.  Can you show your `InfoAdapter` and the layout xml?

Comment: The info adapter is the first block of code above. I just uploaded the layout xml for the position marker A. the POI marker B is (for now) the default infowindow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it. So to get multiple Info windows, I had to get the marker ids corresponding to the markers. So I created a ArrayList that takes in the "id" of the marker.

```
    ArrayList<String> markerPlaces = new ArrayList<>();
```

I then populated it as I add the markers to the map:

```
    Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position)
                        .title(venuesfound.get(i).getName())
                        .snippet("\nOpen: " + venuesfound.get(i).getOpenNow()
                                + "\n(" + venuesfound.get(i).getCategory() + ")")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.measle_blue)));
                markerPlaces.add(marker.getId());
```

Then on the InfoAdapter, I just added a condition that if the marker id is in the ArrayList that I created, then put in a different inflater.

```
    public class InfoAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {
    LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    private TextView textViewstopName;
    private TextView arrivalTime;
    public InfoAdapter(LayoutInflater inflater) {
        this.inflater = inflater;
    }
    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        if (marker != null) {
            if(markerPlaces.containsKey(marker.getId())) {
            ... //Add new inflater here.
            } //checks if the marker is part of the Position marker or POI marker.
            else{
                View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.businfo_layout, null);
                textViewstopName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.businfo);
                textViewstopName.setText(marker.getTitle());
                arrivalTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.arrivalinfo);
                arrivalTime.setText(marker.getSnippet());
                return (v);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        return (null);
    }
}
```

Thank you all for the help! It certainly got me thinking!

Comment: Nice! That's exactly what I was thinking would work.